# Deploy Terraform resource in multiple regions using providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, terraform

I am trying to deploy same instance across multiple regions using providers.
The tree of the folder is:

```
.
|-- main.tf
`-- aws_instance
|   `-- main.tf
`-- versions.tf
```

main.tf looks like:

```
module "aws_instances" {
  source  = "./aws_instance"
  providers = {
    aws.east1 = aws.east1
    aws.east2 = aws.east2
  }
}
```

aws_instance/main.tf looks like:

```
resource "aws_instance" "webserver" {
  ami = "webserver-image"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "EC2-keyPair-Name"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  root_block_device {
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = "30"
    delete_on_termination = false
}
```

versions.tf looks like:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.4"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 3.23.0"
      configuration_aliases = [aws.east1, aws.east2]
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  alias   = "east1"
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-2"
  alias   = "east2"
}
```

With the current code, I am getting the instance deployed in just one region. Any hints of what can be wrong here?

Comment: What is your expected behavior? Also the instance that gets deployed now, which regions is it in?

Comment: @Marcin: I would expect that 2 separate instances are getting deployed in each of the Terraform regions. At the moment, just one instance is deployed in east2.

Comment: Are you sure this is your real code? Your code shouldn't even run, as you do not have provider defined in `aws_instance/main.tf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specifying

```
  providers = {
    aws.east1 = aws.east1
    aws.east2 = aws.east2
  }
```

does not create two instances. It just passes two aliases to your module. But module is still invoked only once. Since you **can't loop** over providers, you have to **explicitly** choose which provider to use for each instance. This means, duplication of code. So you either have to have two definitions of instances in the module:

**aws_instance/main.tf**

```
resource "aws_instance" "webserver1" {
  ami = "webserver-image"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "EC2-keyPair-Name"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  root_block_device {
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = "30"
    delete_on_termination = false

  provider = aws.east1
}

resource "aws_instance" "webserver2" {
  ami = "webserver-image"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "EC2-keyPair-Name"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  root_block_device {
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = "30"
    delete_on_termination = false

  provider = aws.east2
}
```

or **alternatively**, invoke module twice:

**main.tf**

```
module "aws_instance1" {
  source  = "./aws_instance"
  providers = {
    aws = aws.east1
  }
}

module "aws_instance2" {
  source  = "./aws_instance"
  providers = {
    aws = aws.east2
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it seem that this is the only way. Thank you for your suggestion!