# Using a Single Terraform File Across Many Regions/Zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to deploy a single VM (to start) across several regions/zones. My var-file looks like the following:

```
[...]
  "locations": [
    {
      "region": "ca-central-1",
      "zone": "ca-central-1a",
      "image_ami": "ami-0abc4c35ba4c005ca",
      "alias": "cacentral1"
    },
    {
      "region": "eu-west-1",
      "zone": "eu-west-1a",
      "image_ami": "ami-00aa9d3df94c6c354",
      "alias": "euwest1"
    }
  ],
[...]
```

And here is my main.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  c      = length(var.locations)
  region = var.locations[c.index].region # <= PROBLEM
}

module "networkModule" {
  count = length(var.locations)

  source            = "./modules/network"
  region            = var.locations[count.index].region
  app_tag           = var.app_tag
  availability_zone = var.locations[count.index].zone
  public_key_path   = var.public_key_path

  instance_ami = var.locations[count.index].ami

  cidr_block_range         = "10.${count.index * 10}.0.0/16"
  subnet1_cidr_block_range = "10.${count.index * 10}.1.0/24"
  subnet2_cidr_block_range = "10.${count.index * 10}.2.0/24"
}

module "securityGroupModule" {
  source = "./modules/securityGroup"

  count = length(data.networkModule.vpc_id)

  region            = module.networkModule.region[count.index]
  availability_zone = module.networkModule.availability_zone[count.index]
  instance_ami      = module.networkModule.instance_ami[count.index]

  vpc_id  = module.networkModule.vpc_id[count.index]
  app_tag = var.app_tag
}

module "instanceModule" {
  source = "./modules/instance"

  count = length(data.networkModule.vpc_id)

  instance_type      = var.instance_type
  instance_ami       = module.securityGroupModule.instance_ami[count.index]
  availability_zone  = module.securityGroupModule.availability_zone[count.index]
  vpc_id             = module.networkModule.vpc_id[count.index]
  subnet_public_id   = module.networkModule.public_subnets[0]
  key_pair_name      = module.networkModule.ec2keyName[count.index]
  security_group_ids = [module.securityGroupModule.sg_22, module.securityGroupModule.sg_80]
  app_tag            = var.app_tag
}
```

The errors I'm getting are here:

```
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on resources.tf line 12, in provider "aws":
│   12:   region = var.locations[c.index].region
│
│ A managed resource "c" "index" has not been declared in the root module.
╵
```

Is there a way to iterate over many regions with the same terraform deployment?

It appears[1] that it is not possible to loop over providers - is this still the case?

[1] [Deploy Terraform resource in multiple regions using providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73934214/deploy-terraform-resource-in-multiple-regions-using-providers)

Comment: "is this still the case?" Yes it is still not possible to enumerate within a `provider` block; this is true even with the plugin framework updates.

Comment: so what's the pattern for doing the same deployment across many regions? workspaces & bash scripts?

Comment: there is no pattern. Its up to you have you want to do it. Use bash scripts if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically create providers, though it has been considered on a few occasions; [here is maybe the most relevant comment to date on the topic](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24476#issuecomment-700368878). Nevertheless, there are options.

One such option you have, is to create the providers you know are required, then reference these dynamically. Consider the following:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "ca_central_1"
  region = "ca-central-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us_west_1"
  region = "us-west-1"
}

locals {
  things = [
    {
      name   = "foo",
      region = "ca-central-1",
    },
    {
      name   = "bar",
      region = "us-west-1",
    },
    {
      name   = "baz",
      region = "ca-central-1",
    },
  ]
}

data "aws_region" "ca_central_1" {
  for_each = { for thing in local.things : thing.name => thing if thing.region == "ca-central-1" }

  provider = aws.ca_central_1
}

data "aws_region" "us_west_1" {
  for_each = { for thing in local.things : thing.name => thing if thing.region == "us-west-1" }

  provider = aws.us_west_1
}

output "things_in_central" {
  value = data.aws_region.ca_central_1
}

output "things_in_west" {
  value = data.aws_region.us_west_1
}
```

*note: The `aws_region` data sources here aren't really relevant, they are just to illustrate the different region provider being used.*

This yield the outputs:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + things_in_central = {
      + baz = {
          + description = "Canada (Central)"
          + endpoint    = "ec2.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com"
          + id          = "ca-central-1"
          + name        = "ca-central-1"
        }
      + foo = {
          + description = "Canada (Central)"
          + endpoint    = "ec2.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com"
          + id          = "ca-central-1"
          + name        = "ca-central-1"
        }
    }
  + things_in_west    = {
      + bar = {
          + description = "US West (N. California)"
          + endpoint    = "ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
          + id          = "us-west-1"
          + name        = "us-west-1"
        }
    }
```

So essentially, you are just saying, for every resource where I know the region is x, use the provider alias related to x, and y for y, etc.

There is nothing magic here, but more about [filtering elements in for expressions here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#filtering-elements).

You can pass these providers to modules too if required. In your case, a contrived example would be something like:

```
module "security_group_us_west_1" {
  source   = "./modules/security-group"
  for_each = { for network in networks : network.vpc_id => network if network.region == "us-west-1" }

  app_tag           = var.app_tag
  availability_zone = each.availability_zone
  region            = each.region
  vpc_id            = each.vpc_id

  providers = {
    aws = aws.us_west_1
  }
}
```

Where `network` is some data structure, whether it come from local, vars, or another module.

Comment: this is so close! the challenge is the last item in here - where the provider is specifically named. Can that be done programatically? Or does this go back to the original issue of not being able to iterate over providers?

Comment: It can be done programmatically, but not in the HCL. You could probably do it with TFCDK, but I don't know. You could of course generate this code using your language of choice or use a wrapper, but it isn't part of Terraform's native DSL yet and doesn't look like it will be anytime soon. See the comment I linked near the beginning of the post.

Comment: oh! good find. bummer, it's slightly different a concern than listed there, but i see how it's unfortunately lumped in together.